# Magento stuck at "Please Wait" when saving Customer

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.5

I have a problem in my dev Magento store in that I can not save a new customer or edit an existing customer.  I get the "Please Wait" box forever.  The animation in the box moves a frame or two every so often but otherwise doesn't do anything.  If I refresh the page it loads successfully but the changes have not been applied.  I get no errors in the logs or on the page.  All the other questions people have posted about this are either not related to customers or throw errors.  This does nothing....it just sits there.  I think it's failing on the validation, but I don't understand why.  It doesn't even work when I try to hit the "Save" button without making any changes.

I did recently delete some 35000 customers that were imported from our main store, so I figured that might have something to do with it even though it was working since then and only broke recently.  To test I imported an older copy of the database but I continue to have the same problem.  At this point I have to imagine it's a file and not a database issue, but despite reverting all recent changes, nothing has helped.

Does anyone have any suggestions on debugging this and/or have you run into this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the JavaScript console report any errors during this process?

Comment: Use firebug net panel to see response of ajax request. Seems like it returns something wrong.

Comment: Ah HA!  Thanks for the tip on using Firebug...I use it all the time but there are still so many uses for it I haven't explored yet.  The Ajax call returned an error: **Zend_Locale_Exception: No date part in '' found.**  I'm stepping through the code trying to figure it out.  It says I haven't logged in since October 7th, which I'm pretty sure it's accurate.  Perhaps something's been broken for a while.  Any thoughts on where to look?

Comment: GRR!!!  As soon as I added my DOB to the account information it saved successfully.  But DOB isn't required, so what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

This was the first result on Google when searching "save customer account freeze magento" so I figured I'd include my findings here.

Running Magento CE 1.9.1 but this probably applies to most any installation. For my situation, the customer I was trying to modify had an extremely large address book (well over 100 addresses). Due to Magento's mechanism of validating every Form on the "Edit Customer" page, the browser determined that script execution was taking too long and killed the page.

My solution was to delete a bunch of the addresses with the customer's consent.

Add a few breakpoints in the various Form javascript class to see what the hold up is. For me it was a dead giveaway when the validator was attempting to process thousands of elements.